# How do I add Gantt-chart features to a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart of a single person's blood pressure readings. I also know when they started and stopped various anti-hypertensive medications and the doses thereof.

How do I add a box above the blood pressure data to show when any particular drug was started and stopped and restarted and at what dose?

Here is a made-up drawing of what I am trying to do.
[image: graph that I want]

I could probably use the ggtext package but it looks as if it will be a lot of finnicky messing around for what I want to do. Is there a package that specifically adds this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it could be usecase for Paul Murrell's {gggrid} package on github. The package allows you to flexibly draw anything in ggplot2/grid hybrid fashion.

Based on your plot, I'm assuming you have data roughly in the following shapes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gggrid) # remotes::install_github("pmur002/gggrid")
#> Loading required package: grid

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 60, by = 1),
  y = cumsum(rnorm(61))
)
```

Along with some annotations for the treatments.

```r
annotation <- data.frame(
  label = c("Cardelevovol", "Lisinopril 50 mg", "Lisonopril 100 mg"),
  xmin = Sys.Date() + c(0, 0, 40),
  xmax = Sys.Date() + c(40, 20, 60),
  y = c(1, 0, 0),
  fill = c("red", "white", "white")
)
```

We can then define a function that will draw labelled rectangles in the upper margin of the plot.

```r
annotate_fun <- function(data, coords) {
  textheight <- unit(1, "lines")
  
  rectangles <- rectGrob(
    x = (coords$xmin + coords$xmax) / 2,
    width = coords$xmax - coords$xmin,
    y = (data$y + 0.5) * textheight + unit(1, "npc"), 
    height = textheight,
    gp = gpar(fill = coords$fill)
  )
  
  text <- textGrob(
    label = data$label,
    x = (coords$xmin + coords$xmax) / 2,
    y = (data$y + 0.5) * textheight + unit(1, "npc")
  )
  
  gList(rectangles, text)
}
```

Which we can then feed to the `gggrid::grid_panel()` function.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x) +
  grid_panel(
    annotate_fun, data = annotation,
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
        label = label, fill = I(fill), x = NULL)
  ) +
  # Turn off clipping and add some extra margin in top
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(35, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, label, fill
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That is some might complex use of the grid package and the gggrid package neither of which I had used before. It is certainly not high level stuff.  One has to get quite down in the weeds. OK. I am going to try this out.